# Função .ajaxComplete() executa diversas vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quero adicionar esta funcão apos um .ajaxComplete, mas toda vez que um ajax acontece, esse bolco executa uma quantidade de vezes igual a quantidade de ajax que aconteceram.

Por exemplo, se eu clico a primeira vez no botão da classe .chPlus, o console imprime "mais" uma vez;

Quando eu clico novamente, o console imprime mais duas vezes além da primeira, depois 3 vezes e assim por diante.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete( function(){
    $('.chButton').click( function(){
       if($(this).hasClass('chPlus')){
           console.log("mais");
       } else {
           console.log("menos");
       }
    });
});
```

Encontrei uma solução no seguinte tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271198/ajaxcomplete-keeps-stacking-up

A solução seria a função .bind no document.ready com a função do ajax complete. mas não sei fazer ou nao entendi.

Segue a minha implementação:

```
jQuery(document).bind( "ajaxComplete", function() {
    jQuery('.chButton').click( function(){
           if(jQuery(this).hasClass('chPlus')){
               alert("mais");
           } else {
               alert("menos");
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: Quantas vezes voce esta chamando `ajaxComplete`? Tente colocar o seu codigo dentro de `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})` na tentativa de ele nao empilhar..

Comment: O que exatamente você precisa fazer? O ajaxComplete é chamado a cada request(ajax) que é feito, e a cada request feito você está adicionando um listener para o evento de "click" nos elementos com a classe "chButton", logo, o bloco que contém os prints será executado de acordo com o número de requests.

Comment: `ajaxComplete` é um handler (manipulador), ele só executa se você chamar .ajax, .post, .get, .getJSON, .load, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que está a registar múltiplas funções de click no mesmo elemento.

Considere o seguinte código, que ilustra o seu problema:

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
  console.log("B1");
  
  //cada vez que clica no B1 regista outra função de click para o B2
  $("#b2").click(function(){
    console.log("B2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
```

Quantas mais vezes clicar no `b1` mais vezes o `b2` imprime, porque ficou com várias funções de `click`. Uma para cada clique no `b1`.

Tem muitas soluções possíveis. Uma é fazer [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) antes de registar a função de click:

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
  console.log("B1");
  
  $("#b2").unbind("click"); //retirar o click anterior
  $("#b2").click(function(){
    console.log("B2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
```

Agora apenas fará sentido esta solução se o `ajaxComplete` modificar o seu DOM, adicionando por exemplo novos botões `.chButton`. Caso contrário é preferível que defina o código de click do botão `.chButton` fora do `ajaxComplete`, assim:

```
jQuery('.chButton').click( function(){
       if(jQuery(this).hasClass('chPlus')){
           alert("mais");
       } else {
           alert("menos");
       }
});
jQuery(document).bind( "ajaxComplete", function() {
    //Outro código a ser processado quando um pedido ajax termina
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, e o exemplo ilustra muito bem! Usei $(".chPlus").unbind("click");

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a resposta do @Isac, a também os métodos [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) que foram adicionados na versão *1.7 do jQuery*, esses métodos vieram para substituírem os métodos [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) e [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), que a partir da versão *3.0* ficaram obsoletos.

```js
$("#b1").on("click", function(){
  console.log("B1");
  $("#b2").off("click").on("click", function(){
    console.log("B2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
```